# Issue in deleting a child object in Hibernate "deleted object would be re-saved by cascade"

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-cascade

I have the following two entities:

**1- Deal**

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "deal", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch( FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<DealCheckList> dealCheckList;
```

**2- DealCheckList**

```
@JoinColumn(name = "DEAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "DEAL_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
private Deal deal;
```

While deleting child object i.e. DealCheckList using

```
.......
.......  
transaction = session.beginTransaction();

Deal deal = (Deal) session.createCriteria(Deal.class)
                          .add(Restrictions.eq("dealId",  dealId)).uniqueResult();         

for(DealCheckList checklist : deal.getDealCheckList()){                        
            session.delete(checklist);
 }
transaction.commit();
```

I am getting the below error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations):
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the checklist object from the dealCheckList.
Your list of DealCheckList has "cascade all" , so if it has an object in it will automatically be save it.

The error message is pretty clear "remove deleted object from associations"

Comment: Agreed. Error messages don't come much clearer than that :) +1